# How to show block if some button was clicked?

Tags: angular

I need to show this block

```
<div>Hello from some div block!</div>
```

only after pressing (clicking) the button. How can i do that in angular?

I try like

```
<button (click)="assign()">Button</button>
<div *ngIf="assign()">Hello from some div block!</div>
```

But that syntax doesn't work. And unfortunately i didn't find out how can i do that in Angular. I will be grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hnxsg)

Template file

```
<div *ngIf="toggle">Hello from some div block!</div>

<button (click)="assign()">Button</button>
```

Class file

```
toggle: boolean = false;

  assign() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.html

```
<button (click)="assign=true">Button</button>
<div *ngIf="assign">Hello from some div block!</div>
```

.ts

```
assign: boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to toggle display.

**app.component.ts** :

```
show : boolean = false;
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<button (click)="show=true">Button</button>

<div *ngIf="show">Hello from some div block!</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvn6xu

Answer (score 0):

in your ts code add flag and toggling Method :

```
showDiv : boolean = false;
toggleShow() {
 this.showDiv = !this.showDiv;
}
```

and in your HTML :

```
<button (click)="toggleShow()">Button</button>
<div *ngIf="showDiv">Hello from some div block!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.html

```
<button (click)="assign=true">Button</button>
<div *ngIf="assign">Hello from some div block!</div>
```

.ts

`assign: boolean = false;`

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file add.

```
assign: boolean = false;
```

in .component.html file. hide and show the div on click of button using below code.

```
<button (click)="assign=(assign==false?true:false)">Button</button>
<div *ngIf="assign">Hello from some div....</div>
```